# Configuración IP Publica - Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, servidor, docker, redes, ip

Estado intentando configurar una IP publica que adquirí, me enviaron los datos de conexión pero no he podido publicar mi servidor. Ademas requiero asociar unos contenedores Docker para que sean públicos tambien.

Este es mi archivo

> 50-cloud-init.yaml

```
    # This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
    # to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
    # network configuration capabilities, write a file
    # /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
    # network: {config: disabled}
    network:
        version: 2
        renderer: networkd
        ethernets:
            eno1:
                dhcp4: false
                addresses:
                  - 192.168.0.100/24
                  - 101.101.101.101/24
                routes:
                  - to: 0.0.0.0/0
                    via: 192.168.0.1
                    metric: 100
                  - to: 0.0.0.0/0
                    via: 101.101.101.1
                    metric: 100
                nameservers:
                  addresses:
                    - 101.168.101.103
                    - 101.168.101.101
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿ Que significa `no he podido publicar mi servidor` ? ¿ Puedes hacer *ping* desde fuera de tu red ? ¿ No resuelve el nombre ? ¿No accedes a algún servicio concreto ? ¿ Tu conexión es por *router* ? En caso afirmativo, ¿ Que configuración tiene ? ¿ Tienes tu máquina como `DMZ` ?

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder... Tengo entendido que la IP publica me sirve para dejar mi servidor en internet, mi conexión es por Router, y adquirí con Claro dos IP's Publicas, quiero ponerlas en mis servidores y que estos sean accesibles desde internet con dichas IP's. No sé si me hago entender.